# How can I repeat an iteration on an element with an exact index in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array with urls and I have to iterate through it to download the HTML file. The problem that if an url doesn't load, for example due to connection problems, it's HTML file won't be downloaded because the loop goes to the next iteration. My goal would be that if an error occurs, the program should repeat the current iteration for 3 times, and then go to the next iteration.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
let filteredUrls = [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
for (let id in filteredUrls) {
  let currentUrl = filteredUrls[id];
    try {
      //open currentUrl, do some stuff...
    } catch (error) {
      //if there's an error, repeat the current loop 3 times, 
      //after that, move to the next iteration
    }
}
```

How can I do that? Is there a way to do?

Comment: fetching the response from an http request is asynchronous. You'll have to show how you open the url and "do some stuff" with the response.

Comment: For ... In can be used on arrays, but be careful, there is a strong recommendation against it ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in )

Comment: @trincot I open the urls with puppeteer's virtual browser, yes, the whole program is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your download code is async, then you may want to use a recursive function, instead of just re-iterating the loop again.

```
let filteredUrls = [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
for (let id in filteredUrls) {
  let currentUrl = filteredUrls[id];
  downloadFile( currentUrl, 0 );
}

function downloadFile( url, tryCount ) {
  try {
    //open currentUrl, do some stuff...
  } catch (error) {
    tryCount++;
    if ( tryCount < 3 ) {
      downloadFile( url, tryCount );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is async, each call will almost certainly need to be preceded with `await`.

Comment: In that case, he would've to to wrap that callback into a Promise and `await` that for your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how you're fetching the page contents, but I assume you're using something like `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. If you're using fetch, it returns a Promise that rejects on network errors, meaning you can attach a callback to its `.catch()` method that retries the fetch. If you're using XMLHttpRequest, it has an `onerror` event that you can attach the same re-trying callback to instead.

I'd suggest you break out the content-fetching code into a function that accepts a URL and a retry number, then returns either the XMLHttpRequest or `fetch` Promise. That way you can make the error callback just call the same function again, but with `retries-1` passed for the retry parameter.

Examples:

```
function fetchWithRetry(url, tries) {
    if (tries <= 0) { return Promise.reject('Could not fetch.'); }
    return fetch(url).catch(() => fetchWithRetry(url, tries - 1));
}

// OR:

function fetchWithRetry(url, tries) {
  if (tries <= 0) { throw new Error('Could not fetch.'); }
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onerror = () => fetchWithRetry(url, tries - 1);
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}
```

The Promise-based approach is a little nicer because, due to promise chaining, your main code can just assume that the retries are being handled and you can attach a `.then()` which will run if any try succeeds, and a `.catch()` that will only run if all the tries fail. With the XHR, its event-based nature means that if it has to retry, your main code will lose its reference to the current XHR.